# Adding quadratic term changes the sign of the variable

Tags: regression, stata, quadratic-form

Number of books published in a year (noBook) is my dependent variable and I have independent variables including the age of the author (age).

The coefficient of age is positive and it is significant. When I add age^2 to the model, age and age^2 are significant but the sign of age becomes negative.

Could you please advise why it is like that? And, which model should I consider?

Comment: One the given information, it implies the minimum of the fitted quadratic is at a positive age, but doesn't tell you much of anything else. It's not surprising that the coefficient of a variable changes sign when you add another variable.

Comment: You need to tell us what the coefficients actually are. It would also help to know the range of age.

Comment: Also, I hope you are not using OLS regression. Number of books is a count.

Comment: I am using negative binomial regression, range of age is from 1 to 20 since I have considered the career age of the authors.

Comment: @peter The coefficient of age in the first model is 0.0062546 and then in the second model it changes to -0.0297705 while the coefficient of age^2 is 0.0023998 in the second model.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the coefficient of *age* becomes negative doesn't tell you much on its own.  In the new model, the predictive effect of the author's age isn't just represented by an expression of the form $\beta\textit{age}$,  but by a sum $\beta_{1}\mathit{age}^2+\beta_{2}\mathit{age}$.  Assuming that the coefficient of *age* was positive in your first model, I would expect that over the range that you are considering, this quadratic expression is still increasing (check the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial\textit{age}}$ to make sure), indicating that  *nbooks* increases with *age*, even if $\beta_{2}$ is negative.

(This reasoning still holds even if you have interaction terms, but the partial derivative above will take a little more time to compute, and you may have to consider a few more cases).

Comment: Plot the response against age over the range you're considering if you don't know what a partial derivative is.

Answer (score 1):

OK, in your comment you wrote

> The coefficient of age in the first model is 0.0062546 and then in the
>   second model it changes to -0.0297705 while the coefficient of age^2
>   is 0.0023998 in the second model.

If there are no other variables in the model, then this means that e.g. for a 30 year old author, the predicted number of books in model 1 is

```
intercept + .0062545*30 = intercept + 0.19
```

in model 2 it is
    intercept - 0.02977*30 + .0024*900 = intercept + 1.27

Whereas for 60 year olds the effect of the squared term would be much bigger.

```
model 1 = intercept + 0.38
model 2 = intercept + 8.46
```

All this is presuming the modelling is otherwise correct; as I noted, ordinary least squares regression is unlikely to be correct here.